# Unable to parse STL file in Azure Blob Storage with Three.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the [@azure/storage-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) package to [download a STL file blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-nodejs) for use in Three.JS as follows:

```
const downloadResponse = await containerClient.getBlobClient('models/Large Knob.STL').download();
const downloaded = (
  await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody)
).toString(); 
const loader = new STLLoader();
const obj = loader.parse(downloaded);
```

and I load it in a mesh like this:

```
const mesh = new Mesh(model, material);
scene.add(mesh);
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
three.module.js?ffb8:5319 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'center')
    at Sphere.copy (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:5759:28)
    at Frustum.intersectsObject (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:12767:13)
    at projectObject (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:27383:45)
    at projectObject (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:27428:4)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:27212:3)
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:130:30)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:35:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:53:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:58:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:50:16)
    at createScene (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:89:25)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:209:9)
    at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
```

I am able to successfully load and view the mesh if I use `loader.load(<filepath`, but as my file is hosted in Azure blob storage, I don't think this is a viable option. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what STLLoader supports, but if you are running on NodeJS, BlobClient also has `downloadToFile()` and `downloadToBuffer()` methods that might be more convenient. Please check the documentation site for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobclient-downloadtofile

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobclient-downloadtobuffer-1

Comment: downloadToBuffer() is helping wonderfully for loading images, however I think because of the size of the 3D files, javascript can't handle an array that large at once to use STLLoader.parse() on. I got ```RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 15590972817```